# Binding ListBox seletedltems

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework-4

Trying to bind a ListBox c BindingSource.

There is such an entity

```
// Entitys
public class Sp
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? IdTemp { get; set; } //Foreing Key 
    public Temp Temp { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
} 
public class Temp
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Sp> Sps { get; set; } 
}
```

Create BindingSource

```
var b = new BindingSource{ DataSource = new BindingList<Temp>().ToList() };
```

Create a binding

```
listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiSimple;
//Throws an error: 'SelectedItems' because it is read-only
listBox1.DataBindings.Add("SelectedItems", B, "Sps.IdTemp", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer on how to use the `DataSource` and `DataBindings` correctly:
[How to add new item into listbox that using datasource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14958546/how-to-add-new-item-into-listbox-that-using-datasource)

It makes no sense to bind anything to the `SelectedItems` property of `ListBox`.
Instead, you could bind something from your `DataSource` to the `Text` property or similar.